# Regex to catch file name and folder with the same name

Tags: regex, phabricator

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/repo
   /requirements/ 
      base.txt
      something.txt
   requirements.txt
```

I need a regex that tracks if a file is within the requirements folder OR the requirements.txt file.

I have this `@/requirements/*@` that tracks changes in requirements folder, but how do I find requirements.txt

At the same time I don't want it to catch `/repo/apps/myapp/requirements/txt`

Comment: regex is `/requirements/|requirements\.txt$`

Comment: @Mandy8055 close but I wouldn't want `/repo/apps/myapp/requirements.txt`

Comment: Well everything is correct in your example except the one I pointed too. Essentially I just want /requirements/** and requirements.txt at the roor but nothing deeper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex below for your requirements:

```
^\/repo\/requirements\/?.*?$|^\/repo\/requirements\.txt$
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`^, $`** - Represents starting and ending delimiter of the test string.
>
> **`|`** - Represents alternation.
>
> **`^\/repo\/requirements\/?.*?$`** - This part of regex matches any file inside the requirements directory which in turn is just inside root directory.
>
> **`^\/repo\/requirements\.txt$`** - This part of regex matches requirements.txt which is just inside the root directory and not any deeper.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/wOSWLc/5)